# PRESTO SQL conversion into Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, pivot-table, databricks, aggregate-functions, presto

I am converting PRESTO sql to databricks sql. Would you please help me converting the following Subquery.

```
PSF_PIVOT
AS (SELECT A.PATIENT_ID, A.REPORT_ID, A.VISIT_DATE, A.DISEASE_GROUP, 
            MAP_AGG(A.NAME, A.VALUE) AS KV
    FROM PSF_BEST A
    GROUP BY A.PATIENT_ID, A.REPORT_ID, A.VISIT_DATE, A.DISEASE_GROUP
   )
```

I am having trouble converting MAP_AGG part above.

Thanks in Advance!

I tried using MAP instead of MAP_AGG function but ended the following error:

```
[COLUMN_NOT_IN_GROUP_BY_CLAUSE] The expression "NAME" is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in `first()` (or `first_value()`) if you don't care which value you get.
```

There is equivalent PIVOT method for achieving this. But I am not much familiar to this function in Databricks.

Comment: SO is not a free code conversion service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the issue you're having, include both the original code and your efforts to convert it, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Also, the error message is pretty clear and descriptive - the `NAME` column is not present in the GROUP BY statement is self-explanatory. I'm not sure what more we can provide that isn't already in that sentence. Even the error code `[COLUMN_NOT_IN_GROUP_BY_CLAUSE]` tells you what's wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite I would argue that there is enough info and some effort was made and the specific question is asked - how to migrate Presto/Trino specific  `MAP_AGG` to Databricks SQL flavor.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried to put more information on the issue I am having. I understand that SO is not a free code conversion service. I was seeking some help from the people here who already have worked on those functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/map.html) is a scalar function and can't be used as aggregate one. Try using [`map_from_arrays`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/map_from_arrays.html) over aggregated arrays:

```
select ...,
    map_from_arrays(array_agg(A.NAME), array_agg(A.VALUE)) AS KV
from ...
group by
```

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron for your answer. I accept this answer as I have implemented this and getting expected result.